# How many ways to make number length of n from 0, 1 and 2?

Tags: c

You have a number length n, consisting of 3 numbers: 0,1 and 2:
021112201...

a) how many ways to make this number if two zeros can t stay together?
b) how many ways to make this number if two zeros and two ones can t stay together?

I wrote code for solving this below. Is there a way to calculate this task manually with simple formula?

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {   
    int n; //length 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n+1][3];
    a[1][0]=a[1][1]=a[1][2];
    for (int i=2; i<=n; ++i) {
        // only for zeroes
        a[i][0] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][1]+a[i-1][2];
        a[i][1] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][2];
        a[i][2] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][1]+a[i-1][2];
        // for zeroes and ones
        /*
        a[i][0] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][1]+a[i-1][2];
        a[i][1] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][2];
        a[i][2] = a[i-1][0]+a[i-1][1];
        */
     }
     printf("sum: %d;", a[n][0] + a[n][1] +  a[n][2];
     return 0;
```

Comment: if you wrote the code, you have the formula ...

Comment: yes, there is a way to calculate this - and they will know how to do it at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should first sort out your algorithm before you can try to code something in C.

Comment: Avoid smart quotes `“%d”`.  Use quotes `"%d"`.

Comment: `a[1][0]=a[1][1]=a[1][2];` after `int a[n+1][3];` is a problem.  That assigns `a[1][2]` to `a[1][0], a[1][1]`, yet `a[1][2]` value, itself in not yet assigned/initialized.

Comment: So you already have the code that does what you want and now you want help to be able to do it with pen&paper? Hardly a question suitable for SO...

Comment: The branch of maths you want to be looking at is probabilities - that has formulas for working out how many variants there are of things with restrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understand right, your code does not do what it should.
Just to make sure we're talking about the same problem:

```
length 2:
00 not ok
01, 02, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22 ok
length 3:
001,...,200 not ok
010,011,101, 201...,222 ok
```

You want to know the amount of those number marked with "ok".

You can build a tree where every path from the root is a valid number (not containing 00).

```
         /       |       \
     0           1           2
    /  \       / | \       / | \
  1     2    0   1   2    0  1   2
 /|\   /|\  /|  /|\ /|\  /| /|\ /|\
 012   012  12  012 012  12 012 012
```

You need to calculate the number of nodes in the n-th level.

This is the same like asking how long the word produces by a Lindenmayer-System is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system).
'a' represents a 1 or 2 and 'b' represents a 0

```
    a->baa, (when you have a 1 or 2 as first digit, you can add 0, 1, or 2)
    b->aa (when you have a 0 as first digit you can only add 1 or 2)
```

you start with on single 'a' and apply this rules of replacement n times.

```
step 0: a
step 1: b a a
step 2: aa baa baa
step 3: baa baa  aa baa baa aa baa baa
```

You should see the analogy to the tree above.
From this you can get a recursive formula

```
length(n+1)=(length(n)+length(n-1))*2
startig with length(0)=1, length(1)=3
```

The formula should be correct. I haven't found a nice simple formula for this.

The following code should calculate the correct result:

```
int x1 = 1, x2=3;
for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    int x = 2 * (x1 + x2);
    x1 = x2;
    x2 = x
}
// result is in x2
```

The Lindenmayer-System for you 2nd case is:

```
a->ab
b->aab
stating with b
```

Where 'a' is representing 0 or 1 and 'b' is representing 2.
Formula for this case:

```
length(n+1)=length(n)*2+length(n-1)
startig with length(0)=1, length(1)=3
```